# Find what does not exist in another table on a certain date

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I need to find which user did not login today. 
I have 3 tables (users, logs, absence), the log just registers that a user identified by userID has logged in with a timestamp of the login. 
So im trying run a script every night that creates an entry in absence with the users and the time of the absence.

I want to compare userID from table(users) with table(logs) and find which user is missing **today** by looking at the timestamp in the log.createdAt column.

the problem here is "today" , i can find examples here on how to just compare the two tables like this.

```
SELECT userID
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXIST  (
    SELECT userID
    FROM logs 
    WHERE userID = users.userID
)
```

or like this

```
SELECT userID
FROM users LEFT JOIN logs ON users.userID = logs.userID
WHERE  logs.UID is null
```

But this just returns the people who have never been logged at all. 
I'm using sequelize raw query so either a raw query answer or sequelize answer is good

Comment: I thin `users` AND `logs` both table contains timestamp column.
Am i Right?

Comment: if you have time stamp column then you just have to find user who is not login today then you have to set "WHERE" condition between day start and and in "NOT IN" condition of user login table

Comment: @SagarGangwal yes this is true,  both users and log contains the createdAt column with timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT userID
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN logs ON users.userID = logs.userID and DATE(log.createdAt )=DATE(SYSDATE())
WHERE  logs.UID is null
```

Just try above code hope this will helps.

Comment: Hi, this used to work, but sometime ago(maybe the last month) this solution stopped working. Anyone else had this problem?